# Some other process running on port 80 blocks nginx to start

Tags: nginx

I need to configure nginx with virtual hosting. But when I try to start ngnix it fails saying a process is already using port 80. How can I find out which process is using port 80 and kill it so that I can start nginx?

Update:

```
vehico@metaiot:~$ netstat -tulpn
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the following from command shell:

```
sudo lsof -i :80
```

It will show you which process is using it.
**Sudo is important here.**

To kill the process, find the process_id
and then:

```
kill -9 process_id
```

Or in the case of node.js process:

```
pkill -f node
```

- Clarification

> The command **kill** sends the specified signal to the specified
>          processes or process groups.  If no signal is specified, the TERM
>          signal is sent.  This TERM signal will kill processes that do not
>          catch it; for other processes it may be necessary to use the KILL
>          signal (number 9), since this signal cannot be caught.

pkill will send the specified signal (by default SIGTERM) to each process instead of listing them on stdout.

> ```
> -f
> ```
>
> The pattern is normally only matched against the process name. When
>   -f is set, the full command line is used. Means it will kill any process that matches the string given.

Comment: lsof -i :80 doesn't give any response. but netstat -tupl gives here is the response

Comment: I had a typing mistake, corrected it. Try again.

Comment: It still doesn't say anything.

Comment: You need to run it as user root, (using sudo)

Comment: So, have you got an ouput?

Comment: Yes I did. It said NodeJS. Now every time i do sudo fuser -k 80/tcp (this is something I read on many blogpost.) It starts back up. I feel probably something like forever is running but i don't know for sure?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31572/discussion-between-bangal-and-saras-arya).

Answer (score 1):

Running the command

```
netstat -tunlp | grep  :80
```

will help you discover what is listening on port 80.

Once you know that you can take stops to stop/disable it, then you will be able to get nginx to lsten on port 80.

Comment: I did that. It said http. I tried to stop it using sudo fuser -k 80/tcp it didn't work. It used to automatically restart

Comment: I am sorry - I cannot help you with your level of ignorance.

Comment: Can you see the updated question ? And there is no need to be rude here

Comment: Only if you run it with `sudo` will it show the processes.

Comment: What is wrong in my approach? Do you know better ways to kill a process? If yes please enlighten me

Comment: I got it. It is running nodejs. I don't know how it is running ? I never started it. Any way I could stop it? It keeps coming back again @MichaelHampton

Comment: If you never started it probably it's forever running. Which was in my case